# Boolean condition in kotlin was not executing

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, toggle

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)  {
```

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_event)
activity = this@CreateEventActivity
var clicable = true
```

```
val set_data : ArrayList<Category_Spinner_model> = ArrayList<Category_Spinner_model>()

if(clicable) dropdown_lay.setOnClickListener{
    category_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    set_data.add(Category_Spinner_model(R.drawable.ic_facebook,"Entertainment",R.drawable.ic_dropdown_arrow))
    set_data.add(Category_Spinner_model(R.drawable.ic__entertainment,"Entertainment",R.drawable.ic_dropdown_arrow))
    set_data.add(Category_Spinner_model(R.drawable.ic__entertainment,"Entertainment",R.drawable.ic_dropdown_arrow))
    val adapter = Category_recycler_view(set_data)
    category_recycler.adapter = adapter
    clicable = false
    Log.e("clicable->","$clicable")
}



else if(!clicable) dropdown_lay.setOnClickListener{
     set_data.clear()
     val adapter = Category_recycler_view(set_data)
     category_recycler.adapter = adapter
     clicable = true
  
 }
```

}

I have a recycler view and set data to that recycler view via adapter i need to show the recycler view when clicked and remove the recycler on other click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is out of place.

```
if(clicable) dropdown_lay.setOnClickListener{
   ...
}
```

Put it inside the `onClickListener` like this instead.

```
dropdown_lay.setOnClickListener{
     if (clicable) {
          category_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            ...
            ...
          clicable = false
     } else {
          set_data.clear()
            ...
            ...
          clicable = true
     } 
}
```